# Send Multiple command in php Socket (XML)

Tags: php, sockets

I am trying to send multiple command to socket with XML method

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
$host    = "127.0.0.1";
$port    = "1234";
$message = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<command name="login">
<param type="string">username</param>
<param type="string">password</param>
</command>';
echo "Message To server :".$message;
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
$result = socket_connect($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not connect to server\n");
socket_write($socket, $message, strlen($message)) or die("Could not send data to server\n");
$result = socket_read ($socket, 2084) or die("Could not read server response\n");
echo "Reply From Server  :".$result;
socket_close($socket);
?>
```

I am getting Proper response
but when i am tring to send another command like

```
 $message = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <command name="userlist">
</command>';
```

i am not getting response,
SO my question is how to send multiple request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got the solution
need to send two separate message, with new `socket_write` and `socket_read` functions

Comment: Could you please share the code that worked for you? Thanks in advance.